# Browserify + AngularJS index.js IIFE params undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, parameters, iife

I have the following `index.js` for an angular app. Even though the var statements are executed first, and all variables are successfully logged to the console before the IIFE is executed, they are undefined once it steps into the IIFE scope, with the exception of angular. Presumably angular is defined, because angular is a global object. I've seen `window` and `jquery` passed in the same way. I'm just wondering if there is a way for me to pass these locally declared objects to my app's main IIFE script like this? Did I do it wrong? Please help - I'm stumped.

```
var angular = require('angular'),
    config = {
        params: require('./config/params').config,
        routes: require('./config/routes').config
    },
    x = {};


(function (angular, config, x) {

    // *****angular is the only one of these parameters that is defined here

    console.info(angular) // works
    console.info(config) // undefined
    console.info(x) // works
})(angular, config, x);
```

**Updated**

As a commenter pointed out, this is an issue with browserify. If I pass an object I declare literally, it works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Here's my browserify command:

```
browserify -e -d src/index.js -p [minifyify --map sourcemap.json --output sourcemap.json --uglify] > build/index.js
```

(I removed the parameter value and shortened the paths for brevity.)

Comment: This seems specific to the `require` method / amd loader you use, since it all [does work if you stub that part out](https://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/p5L4s1hk/). Could you try to remove the code that is irrelevant, and make the repro minimal as possible? And possibly tag with the module loader you use?

Comment: @Jeroen which code do you consider to be irrelevant, exactly?

Comment: I tested your theory and you are correct. Tagged browserify above

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, during root cause analysis (e.g. remove lines of code that do not make the problem disappear) you'll surely find several. For one, I hazard a guess that not *all* of the arguments are needed for a repro, nor would all the chained calles on the angular module, or the `for` loop. I'd guess about 1/3 of the code is probably enough for a repro?

Comment: @Jeroen - updated. I still think it is weird that angular is working, since I'm requiring it with browserify as well.

Comment: angular uses IIFEs, and my local modules are CommonJS. In case you are unfamiliar, it means that each module exports the function on module.exports.